# Node fs is not replacing the file as expected

Tags: node.js, gulp, fs, eslint

I'm using the fs to write the results of eslint at a html page, but the fs is appending the results on the html file and is not replacing the file as i'd expected.
This is my task:

```
gulp.task('lint',function () {
return gulp.src(config.paths.js)
    .pipe(lint({configFile:'eslint.config.json'}))
    .pipe(lint.format(lintreport,function (results) {
        fs.writeFileSync(path.join(config.paths.dist,'results.html'),results,{'flag': 'w'});
    }))
    .pipe(connect.reload());});
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: This shouldn't necessarily matter but, for starter the option is `flag` not `flags`.

Comment: It's just a typo, i tried without `flag` because the deafaults is `w`, it was just a desesperate attempt =)
Really it does not matter, just bothers me.